# How to set a text as a footer with Pages?

Tags: pages

I woudld like to set a footer on my page, in order to make some annotation, like this picture.

[image: example]

I would like to make something like the number **3**.

I am using Pages from Mac OS X :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature you are looking for are the [footnotes/endnotes](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH15341?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)

> A document can contain footnotes, which appear at the bottom of the
>   page, or endnotes, which appear at the end of the document or a
>   section. You can’t have both footnotes and endnotes in the same
>   document, but you can convert all notes in the document from one type
>   to another.
>
> By default, footnotes and endnotes are numbered continuously
>   throughout the document with Arabic numerals, but you can change this
>   formatting.
>
> You can also restyle the text used within the note. For example, you
>   can italicize or underline a book title within the note.
>
> Use the Footnotes pane of the Format inspector to format footnotes and
>   endnotes.

[image]

> **Insert a footnote, endnote, or section endnote**
>   The first time you
>   insert a note, it’s a footnote by default. If you want document or
>   section endnotes rather than footnotes, you must first add a footnote
>   and then convert it to an endnote.
>
> 1. Click in the text where you want to insert the symbol for a footnote
>      or endnote.
> 2. Click Insert in the toolbar, then choose Footnote.
>
> The symbol is inserted in the text and the insertion point moves to
>   the footnote text field at the bottom of the page.
>
> 3. Enter the footnote text.